# Speeding up closest date merge in Pandas?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, merge

I have two data frames with time columns and value columns, `df1` and `df2`. `df1` is shape `[30000000 x 20]` and `df2` is shape `[400 x 20]`. I need to create a new column in `df1` that contains a value from `df2` from the row in `df2` with the closest date. This is how I'm doing it:

```
    df2= df2.sort_values(by='time_col').reset_index(drop=True)

    df1['closest'] = np.searchsorted(df2['time_col'].values, df1['time_col'].values)
    df1['new_values'] = [df2.loc[x, 'value_col'] for x in sales['closest']]
```

This works, but takes an enormously long time. As in, several hours for a data frame that is 30 million rows.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dude, just use `Pandas 19.0` and the new amazing `merge as_of` for time-series

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#merging-asof